# Error creating react app using create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs

C: \Users›create-react-app my-app
Creating a new React app

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template
npm ERR! code E403
mpm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden- GET https://registry.npmjs.org/open/-/open-8.4.0.t
npm ERE: 46B In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
mpm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Aborting installation.
pm install
--no-audit
--save
--save-exact
--loglevel error react react-dom re
Deleting generated file...
Deleting my-app/ from C: \Users
Done.
package, json

Comment: Please ask a specific question about your problem

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to create a new react-app first of all make sure your node version is 14 or above then use

```
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

for more details please visit [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Comment: node version 16.14 and npm 7.24.2